Crooked cops tries to kill a black man
I'm looking for an action film with two men, one of them black, who walks into a bar and then there's crooked cops who wants the black man dead. The only other thing I remember is that the final scene took place in a city bus with newspapers on the sides. Bruce Willis may have starred in it. I saw this movie about a year ago, but it had already been released for some time.

More details please. Including when you saw it.

Be sure to not rely on the question title to make up a complete and appropriate question, but put all neccessary information into the question body.

@SystemDown - to be fair, he does say he saw it about a year ago - but more detail would be good.

I'm not entirely sure why, but I immediately thought of 16 Blocks. I only saw it when it came out in 2006, so, I don't remember much from it, but I'm pretty sure that they are held up in a bus close to the end of the movie. Bruce Willis did star in it, and his character was assigned to transport a black convict to a courthouse a few (16) blocks away. If I recall correctly they did also stop by at a bar. This, along with the following summary that I got from IMDb, suggests that this is indeed the correct movie.

Jack Mosley, a burnt-out detective, is assigned the unenviable task of transporting a fast-talking convict from jail to a courthouse 16 blocks away. However, along the way he learns that the man is supposed to testify against Mosley's colleagues, and the entire NYPD wants him dead. Mosley must choose between loyalty to his colleagues and protecting the witness, and never has such a short distance seemed so long...


Does this movie bear a strong resemblance to The Gauntlet to anyone else?

@Paulster2 Now that you say it some themes are in fact similar, the witness, the corrupt cops, the secured bus. But most of that you can find in many movies and the bus scene is quite different, only rough similarities I'd say (but maybe sufficient for a "was it inspired by..."-question?).
